# How can like 'z%' in eclipse query when 'z' is my parameter

Tags: sql, eclipse

For example

```
select custName 
from Customer
where custName like '%john%';
```

My parameter is custName, so in query Eclipse Birt report, I used

```
select custName 
from Customer
where custName like '%?%';
```

But it wont work, how can I make this possible. I need help. Can anyone solve this matter?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the wildcard characters (`%`) in the parameter value.

For example

```
-- Parameter Value = "%john%"

SELECT custName from Customer WHERE custName LIKE ?
```

Answer (score 1):

In Standard SQL, for which the concatenation symbol is `||` it would be:

`WHERE custName LIKE '%' || :param_name || '%';`

Guessing a translation to Eclipse:

`WHERE custName LIKE CONCAT('%', param_name, '%');`

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, nearly 4 years later, this seems to work:

```
WHERE custName LIKE '%' || ? || '%'
```